# Math-pow incorrect results

Tags: c#, math, floating-point

```
            double a1;
        a1 = Math.Pow(somehighnumber, 40);
        something.Text = Convert.ToString(xyz);
```

the result i get is have E+41 etc. 
its like 1,125123E+41 etc. i dont get why.

Comment: How do you want it to display? How can C# read your mind?

Comment: Did you just paste some code in at random?  What is somehighnumber?  What is numberofloopdub?

Comment: Double only has a lmited significant amount of digits anyways, so if String.Format displayed all the digits by default, you would just get a lot of zeroes in the end.

Comment: What do you expect to get? What's the value of `somehighnumber`? Is it about 10.029516567? What's the relation between it and `numberofloopdub`?

Comment: i just made result in my mind, no such a value exist but i can tell that value is always changing but very high numbers im talking about here.

Comment: @steve, no such a value exist, i just made that values in my mind. but i can tell that they are high.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's `10.029516567`, give or take.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If what you want to do is display a *double-precision floating point number* without the scientific notation then use the **standard number formatting specifier**:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N}", Math.Pow(10, 100)));
```

Results in:

```
10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.00
```

If what you have a problem with is that the result is rounded off, then don't use double-precision floats; they are accurate to only 15 decimal places. Try doing your arithmetic in BigIntegers, which have arbitrary integer precision.

Comment: @Eric do you know if there are any plans on introducing something with more digits than a decimal type for floats?

Comment: @Yuriy: I am not aware of any such plans, but that doesn't mean there aren't any; there are a lot of teams working on various aspects of technical computing at Microsoft and perhaps one of them is working on such a thing. (If the subject of programming tools for technical computing interests you, you might consider looking into Sho, from Microsoft Research; it's pretty slick.)

Comment: @Yuriy: And of course it is easy to build your own arbitrary-precision decimal floating point type by simply making a struct that contains two BigIntegers -- one for the mantissa, and one for the exponent. Getting all the math right is not actually that hard. Doing it super-efficiently is a bit trickier.

Comment: @Eric looks very nice. I mostly need this for Project Euler :)

Comment: @Yuriy: Oh, and I forgot to mention, there is an arbitrary precision rational class available in Microsoft Solver Framework. See my recent post on taking apart a double for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/17/looking-inside-a-double.aspx

Comment: BigRational from the BCL team is available here: http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782

Comment: @Eric thanks, the answer turned out to be Diophantine pairs. Excellent job on the interview blog.

Answer (score 7):

That's [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). It means 1.125123 * 10<sup>41</sup>. Scientific notation is useful if your number becomes so large that displaying it in full would require a lot of screen space. Also, floating point arithmetic is not precise so even if you did display the number in full most of the digits would be incorrect anyway.

If you want precise calculations you should use [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) instead of `double` (this type is present in .NET 4.0 or newer).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how can i turn it into some normal number ?

Comment: @user646317: It is a normal number. But of course, you are free to write it `112512300000000000000000000000000000000000` if you prefer that...

Comment: You could write a function that parses out the number after then E, counts the number of digits after the decimal, removes the decimal, and spits out (# after E - # of digits after decimal) zeros. But most people prefer to see scientific notation, since it means the same thing, and you don't have to count zeros to figure out how big the number is. Likewise, instead of writing "1 googol," you *could* write 100000000000000000000... okay I'm not really going to write 100 zeros. But seriously, there's a reason for words like "billion," "googol," and scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
double bigNum = Math.Pow(100, 100);
string bigString = string.Format("{0:F}", bigNum);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString

Or you can use the 4.0 indroduced [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)(add a reference to `System.Numerics` to the Project):

```
Numerics.BigInteger bigInt = Numerics.BigInteger.Pow(1000, 1000);
string veryBigString =  bigInt.ToString("F");
```

As you can see it also works with `ToString`.